# How to use ellipsis (…) in nested for loop

Tags: terraform

I see this error "If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key."

```
locals {
  key_id = {
    for x in var.security_rules :
  "${x.type}" => x}
}
```

Is it possible to use ellipsis in a nested for this loop and how can i do it?

Answer (score 10):

The error message means that `var.security_rules` has multiple items with the same type. For example:

```
variable "security_rules" {
  default = [
    {
      type = "a"
    },
    {
      type = "b"
    },
    {
      type = "a"
    }
  ]
}
```

We can see that there are at least 2 items with the same `type`, which wont be accepted as key in map. What we can do here is to group the items with the same `type`. This is exactly what `ellipsis (...)` will accomplish. So:

```
locals {
  key_id = {
  for x in var.security_rules : "${x.type}" => x... }
}
```

The value of `key_id` in this example will be:

```
key_id = {
  "a" = [
    {
      "type" = "a"
    },
    {
      "type" = "a"
    },
  ]
  "b" = [
    {
      "type" = "b"
    },
  ]
}
```